# File synchronization library

Tags: c++, database, networking, synchronization

I'm looking into C/C++ libraries (Win/Linux) that allow me to synchronize information over network. I want to run multiple instances of my program (on different PC's), and want to synchronize files locally instead of accessing files remotely over the network at a single location.

If all instances are to maintain DB consistency it also needs to bee aware of any message delivery errors, so an ack mechanism is necessary.

I stumbled into a couple of solutions, but I'm still trying to figure out what my best solution would be.

Any suggestions are appreciated and feel free to ask about any clarifications.

---

Edit

I've been looking into enet and UDT does anyone has any experience using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the design space for such a thing is pretty huge, but it reminded me of a kinda cool library I saw the other day, [VAST](http://vast.sourceforge.net/).  The idea is that it's a spatially-represented distributed publish/subscribe model.  Maybe it is adaptable to your purpose.

Another thing that is probably immediately useful if you are most interested in *file* synchronisation -- [librsync](http://librsync.sourceforge.net/).  It implements the rsync delta algorithm, by the looks.